# Swap rows and columns of a table in sql server select

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Denomination                     | Count
----------------------------------------
Cnanaya Catholic                 | 17
RC Latin Catholic                | 28
RC Syrian Catholic               | 3
```

I want to swap the rows and columns like below

```
Cnanaya Catholic | RC Latin Catholic | RC Syrian Catholic
---------------------------------------------------------
17               | 28                | 3
```

Please help with any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using PIVOT like below :

Suppose your current result is by grouping like :

```
SELECT Denomination, count(id) as count
from table
group by Denomination
```

Your pivot query will be like :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Denomination, id from table) d
PIVOT (COUNT(id) FOR Denomination IN ([Cnanaya Catholic],[RC Latin Catholic],[RC Latin Catholic],[RC Syrian Catholic])) p
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sql server `PIVOT`

Answer (score 0):

This is an row2column problem.
Try this:

```
select 
  sum(case Denomination when 'Cnanaya Catholic' then Count end) CnanayaCatholic,
  sum(case Denomination when 'RC Latin Catholic' then Count end) RCLatinCatholic,
  sum(case Denomination when 'RC Syrian Catholic' then Count end) RCSyrianCatholic
from YOURTABLE t;
```

Comment: If your oracle is Oracle 11,you can use PIVOT.

Comment: The OP is not on Oracle but same applies if their SQL Server Version is 2005+

Comment: @Upendra I tried it on my plsql(oracle).But I didn't try it on sql server.Perhaps you are right.